# Use of Aspectj in jsp based java applications

Tags: java, jsp, aspectj

How to used aspectj to find pointcuts for JSP based java applications.  I want to capture automatically before and after when a code called.

Comment: JSP is a view template technology; aspects are clearly on the server side.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Anuj. Please be so kind as to improve your question by editing it, providing more details (and the source code your are having problems with) in order to have a chance to get any meaningful answers. Please read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to prepare one. If your problem is reproduceable for others, they can more effectively help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use AspectJ (AOP) either compile time (or) load time. Please follow the link to define pointcut https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj.

Also Using ASM -it is java bytecode library - you can inject bytecode where a method begin and method end, etc. https://asm.ow2.io/

Comment: Jsp based application does not class and method then how i can use check execution of a page using Aspectj and define pointcuts.

Comment: Every java based application should have class & methods. JSP is converted into servlet (it is a .java file) and the servlet is compiled into .class file which is done by the server (like tomcat ,jboss etc.). Remember everthing you write in the JSP is converted into jspInit() , _jspService() & jspDestroy().. Refer the link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/life-cycle-of-jsp/

Comment: How to get any variable value or any cookie value from class and method using Aspectj ?